# null pointer exception when get List from a class

Tags: java, nullpointerexception

I have File class that contains following code

```
private List<TaggedDetail> tags =  new ArrayList<TaggedDetail>();
public List<TaggedDetail> getTags() {
    return tags;
}
public void setTags(List<TaggedDetail> tags) {
    this.tags = tags;
}
```

In another class, I call file.getTags(). However it returns null. Why?

Comment: Perhaps something has called `setTags(null)`?

Comment: No @javaBeginner the default would be OK

Comment: @javaBeginner If the list is empty, and I called file.getTags(). It will return null? I did not set anything to the list. (I didn't use file.setTags())

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems someone is setting the tags list to null.
Would recommend putting in a breakpoint at setTags methods to check.

Comment: I am using GAE datastore. In datastore, tags field is empty. Is this a problem?

Comment: @Lin in list `Empty` and `null` are have a huge difference.

Comment: @sᴜʀᴇsʜᴀᴛᴛᴀ I know the different between Empty and null. The file object is retrieve from datastore. In datastore, the tags field is still empty. So maybe, datstore return list as null instead?

Comment: @Lin See the source  code of your datastore and see what it is  returning if no records found.

Answer (score 0):

You say in one of your replies that you are not calling `file.setTags(null)` anywhere. In that case I can only guess that the null pointer exception you are getting when you call `file.getTags()` is because you have not initialised `file`. Check `(file == null)` first.

Alternatively perhaps there is some other code in the `File` class that is setting the list to `null`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you those who helped me out.
I tried checking (file.getTags() == null) in datastore.

It return true at first. So I tried to debug again, and it return false. There is nothing wrong with my code but may be the GAE has some delay or bug.